# How to find the sum of infinite series $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{\cos(\frac{2k\pi T}{\log q}) }{16k^2\pi^2+\log^2q}$

Tags: calculus

I need to evaluate this sum, where $T, q>0$. Pls help.

Comment: Analytically or numerically?

Comment: It's sufficient to evaluate something like
$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\cos\left(ka\right) \over k^{2} + b^{2}}$.

Comment: Numerically @AlexisOlson

Comment: How? @FelixMarin

Comment: You have too many constant arounds $\left(~2, \pi, T, q,16,\ldots ~\right)$. Make $a \equiv {2\pi T \over \log\left(q\right)}$ and $b \equiv \left\vert{\log\left(q\right) \over 4\pi}\right\vert$. Then, you'll have ${1 \over 16\pi^{2}}\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}{\cos\left(ka\right) \over k^{2} + b^{2}}$

Comment: Sorry, I asked you how to evaluate the sum you write, which is a same as my sum in the begining) @FelixMarin

Comment: It's not an 'elementary' function. $\texttt{Mathematica}$ yields a result in terms of $\mathsf{Hypergeometric\ Functions}$.